# React router dom navigating to wrong path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

We are using React-Router-DOM v6.19.0 and there are two you can find below.

```
<Route path="/route1/*" element={<RouteOneList />} />
<Route path="/route1/:one/:two/:three" element={<RouteAnother />} />
```

and in `RouteOneList` it has sub routes

```
<Route path="/add/:type/:id" element={<AddComponent />} />
```

Here I am trying to access

`"/route1/add/test/1"` - It is supposed to load `AddComponent` but it's falling into `<RouteAnother />` component.

Is there any way tackle this problem? I have tried changing the order but that also not helped me.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what RouteOneList is? From what I can see the route should be `add/:type/:id` instead of `/add/:type/:id`, but you could still be facing problems depending on what RouteOneList actually is. Try changing the route and test... If it works, great, if not please add more details.

Comment: Thanks @SharpDev. Here RouteOneList act as layout and it will have one button. When button click we are navigating to add/:type/:id relative to the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that the `Routes` component only handles matching the routes it renders directly. The `"/route1/add/test/1"` path can be matched by the `"/route1/:one/:two/:three"` path and so that is what is matched and rendered.

## Solution

Based on your comment in another answer that `RouteOneList` is a layout with a button I suggest actually using it as a layout route. Instead of `RouteOneList` rendering ***descendent*** routes it should instead render an `Outlet` component for ***nested*** routes. This is so the main `Routes` component can know of and match `"/route1/:one/:two/:three"` ***and*** `"/route1/add/:type/:id"`.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const RouteOneList = () => (
  <>
    ...
    <Outlet />
    ...
  </>
);
```

```
<Routes> // <-- knows of all routes for matching/rendering
  <Route path="/route1">
    <Route element={<RouteOneList />}> // <-- layout route
      <Route path="add/:type/:id" element={<AddComponent />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path=":one/:two/:three" element={<RouteAnother />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

### Demo

[image: Edit react-router-dom-navigating-to-wrong-path]